# How to configure pppoe client on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

I have an OpenBSD 5.1 installed + a cable from my ISP. I have the username/password for the PPPoE connection, but how can I configure the connection to be permanent? (I have 1 interface on the machine.)

UPDATE: according to google I will need to fill out the /etc/ppp/ppp.conf file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0)

```
lii0 is the WAN interface
```

1)

```
echo "up" > /etc/hostname.lii0
```

2)

```
vi /etc/hostname.pppoe0 
inet 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 NONE \
pppoedev lii0 authproto pap \
authname 'PPPOEUSERNAME' authkey 'PPPOEPASSWORD' up
dest 0.0.0.1
!/sbin/route add default -ifp pppoe0 0.0.0.1
```

3)

```
sh /etc/netstart
```

Answer (score 1):

Never tried to configure PPP myself, but there is a excellent FAQ on the OpenBSD homepage, including examples for configuring PPP: http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#PPP